# Qt application doesn't load qsvg.dll

Tags: windows, qt, svg

I'm trying using svg images in my Qt(**5.6.3**) app (on Windows 10). But it's so weird that my qt app doesn't even load qsvg(d).dll while other dlls in imageformats(**qtiff(d).dll, qico(d).dll, qjpeg(d).dll**, etc.) were already loaded correctly after started...
I was using svg image as image/border-image/background-image in .ui file through QStyleSheet property.
Do I need extra configurations in Visual Studio projects or qt.conf?
Does anyone can help? I'm kinda desperate.

Comment: You may need to deploy also `qsvgicon.dll` (located in `iconengines` plugin folder) along with your app.

Comment: @V.K. I found a solution. I need to include some header files in QtSvg to make the binary load qtsvg.dll even I didn't code any svg related lines. .ui file won't tell qt maker 'I need svg capabilities'. Thanks very much though~

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I need to include some header files in QtSvg(I used qtsvgglobal.h, and qsvgwidget.h has been verified working) to make the binary load qtsvg.dll even I didn't code any svg related lines. .ui file won't tell qt maker 'I need svg capabilities'.

Comment: Do you have `QT += svg` in your PRO file? It could help too. The solution you suggest feels like a strange hack.